# Using map to iterate a function that left_joins

Tags: r, function, loops, merge, left-join

I have two df that look something like this:

```
df1 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), Toaster = c(rep(1, 3), rep(0, 3)),radio=c(rep(0, 3), rep(1, 3)),year=c(2016,2018,2016,2019,2020,2021))
df2 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(1,1, 2,2, 3,3), State = c(rep("Alabama", 4), rep("Ohio", 2)),value=rnorm(6),year=seq(2016,2021,1))
```

Where the `Toaster` and the `radio` variables in `df1` indicate in which year the consumer bought a toaster.
Generally speaking, my aim is to extract key information from some observation in df1, and then join them to df2. More precisely I would like to create a new variable in df2 that indicates the first year in which the consumer bought a `Toaster` or a `radio`. In the real data I need to iterate this procedure for a large number of products.
To achieve my aim I have created a function that does what I need.

```
first_buy <- function(var1){
  yo <- df1
  yo<-setDT(yo)[get(var1)==1
  ][order(year), buycount:= seq_len(.N), by = CustomerId
  ][buycount==1,first_buy_date:=year] 
  first_buy<-yo%>%select(CustomerId,first_buy_date)%>%
    distinct()
  df2 <- left_join(df2,first_buy) %>% 
    setnames("first_buy_date",paste("first_buy", (var1),sep = "_"))
    return(df2)
}
```

If I use the function on each variable individually it works perfectly providing the expected outcome

```
df2<- first_buy("Toaster")
df_final_correct<- first_buy("radio")
print(df_final_correct)
   CustomerId   State      value year first_buy_Toaster first_buy_radio
1           1 Alabama -1.3507808 2016              2016              NA
2           1 Alabama -1.3507808 2016                NA              NA
3           1 Alabama -0.3957899 2017              2016              NA
4           1 Alabama -0.3957899 2017                NA              NA
5           2 Alabama  0.1681513 2018              2016            2019
6           2 Alabama  0.8138573 2019              2016            2019
7           3    Ohio -0.8039992 2020                NA            2020
8           3    Ohio -0.8039992 2020                NA              NA
9           3    Ohio  1.0181946 2021                NA            2020
10          3    Ohio  1.0181946 2021                NA              NA
```

However, when I try to iterate this over a number of variable, the function provides a different output.

```
df1 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), Toaster = c(rep(1, 3), rep(0, 3)),radio=c(rep(0, 3), rep(1, 3)),year=c(2016,2018,2016,2019,2020,2021))
df2 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(1,1, 2,2, 3,3), State = c(rep("Alabama", 4), rep("Ohio", 2)),value=rnorm(6),year=seq(2016,2021,1))

itervar <- c("Toaster","radio")
df_final_wrong <- map_df(itervar,~first_buy(.x))
   CustomerId   State      value year first_buy_Toaster first_buy_radio
1           1 Alabama -1.2601968 2016              2016              NA
2           1 Alabama -1.2601968 2016                NA              NA
3           1 Alabama  0.9254294 2017              2016              NA
4           1 Alabama  0.9254294 2017                NA              NA
5           2 Alabama -0.3375396 2018              2016              NA#duplicated
6           2 Alabama -0.6909882 2019              2016              NA#duplicated
7           3    Ohio -0.1396262 2020                NA              NA
8           3    Ohio -1.3716387 2021                NA              NA
11          2 Alabama -0.3375396 2018                NA            2019 #duplicated
12          2 Alabama -0.6909882 2019                NA            2019#duplicated
13          3    Ohio -0.1396262 2020                NA            2020
15          3    Ohio -1.3716387 2021                NA            2020
```

The issue is that it duplicates the results for `CustomerId==2`.
Does anyone knows how I could modify my function `first_buy` so that it iterates correctly?. I am not sure why the lef_join does not work as expected with iterations.

Thanks a lot for your help

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the function manually :

```
df2<- first_buy("Toaster")
df_final_correct<- first_buy("radio")
```

Notice that you store the results of `first_buy("Toaster")` in `df2` which changes `df2`. When you are running `first_buy("radio")` you have a changed `df2` which is different than original `df2`. `map` does not provide you that changed `df2` in second iteration.

A simple solution to get changed `df2` in every iteration is to use `for` loop.

```
for(item in itervar) {
  df2 <- first_buy(item)
}
df2

#   CustomerId   State      value year first_buy_Toaster first_buy_radio
#1           1 Alabama -0.1296113 2016              2016              NA
#2           1 Alabama -0.1296113 2016                NA              NA
#3           1 Alabama  0.3220200 2017              2016              NA
#4           1 Alabama  0.3220200 2017                NA              NA
#5           2 Alabama -0.5530528 2018              2016            2019
#6           2 Alabama -0.2761895 2019              2016            2019
#7           3    Ohio  1.9671128 2020                NA            2020
#8           3    Ohio  1.9671128 2020                NA              NA
#9           3    Ohio -0.2282965 2021                NA            2020
#10          3    Ohio -0.2282965 2021                NA              NA
```

Comment: Nice, this is excellent! My only question is there a way to do this using map or apply? or it is necessary to use map. I thought that map worked as for loops.

Comment: For most cases, yes `map` works as for loops. However, if you have condition when your current output is dependent on previous input `map` will not work.